# Как сделать блок с такой рамкой

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: Как сделать блок с такой рамкой]

линию не сложно
тег заголовка абсолютом ставишь на линию родителя
у заголовка линия слева и вверху
и псевдо елементом эта наклонная линия делается
фон у заголовки белы и он перекроет линию родителя
Это мне посоветовали.
вот что у меня получилось[image: мое]

что я делаю не так?[image: css][image: html]

```
<setion class="popup">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <col-6>
                    <div class="popup__title-wrapper">
                        <h1>Бизнес центр Space Tower / Офисное помещение 1862 кв.м</h1>
                        <div><span>
                            Здание
                        </span><span >
                            Офисное помещение
                          </span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <h2 class="title card__title">
                            Параметры здания 
                        </h2>
                        <div class="card__body-card">
                            <div class="card__body-card-item">
                                <span>Адрес:</span><span> Шмитовский проезде, 37</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </col-6>
                <col-6>
                    <div class="btn-wrapper">
                        <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
                    </div>
                </col-6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </setion>

.popup {
  &__title-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
}

.card {
  position: relative;

  &__title {
    border-top: solid 1px #979797;
    border-left: solid 1px #979797;
    width: 30%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: $secondaryFont;
    padding: 14px 54px;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -44px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: $waht;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      width: 53px;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #979797;
      position: absolute;
      right: -14px;
      top: 21px;
      transform: rotate(58deg);
    }
  }

  &__body-card {
    width: 802px;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px #979797;
    padding: 56px;
  }

  &__body-card-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

Comment: Добрый вечер! Не могли бы Вы выложить свой код не скриншотами, а прямо в формате кода, выделив его тремя косыми кавычками ( ` )?

Comment: и overflow:hidden; не помогает

Comment: @ВиталийДякин заментите top right left на margin-top margin-right margin-left

Answer (score 2):

На лучшее решение не претендую, ложился спать уже, перед сном головоломку захотелось...

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card__title {
  width: 30%;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 54px;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #eee;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 86% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  /*background-color: $waht;*/
}

.card__body-card {
  width: 802px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px #979797;
  padding: 56px;
}

.card__body-card-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h2 class="title card__title">
    Параметры здания
  </h2>
  <div class="card__body-card">
    <div class="card__body-card-item">
      <span>Адрес:</span><span> Шмитовский проезде, 37</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но нужно без линии

Comment: @ВиталийДякин с `border` без доп линии такое сделать будет тяжело я думаю. По крайне мере, я вспомнить не могу как сделать. Но если убрать `border` и использовать заливку, можно довольно легко реализовать (я свой код подправил, посмотрите)

Comment: @Pilaton уберите везде бордеры и сделайте заливку везде, думаю норм вариант

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```css
.box {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 150px auto 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}

.box__title {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.box__title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  right: -12px;
  top: -1px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  transform: skew(30deg, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__title">
    <span>werskbjds</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box__content">
    dgfgdsg
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Учитель написал ответ))))

Answer (score 2):

Если использовать `background: linear-gradient` и "технику" отрисовки линий этим правилом, можно сделать более универсальное решение, которое может растягиваться относительно высоты дочернего блока.

```css
:root {
  --tabs-border-weight: 1px;
  --tabs-border-color: #666;
  --tabs-background: #ccc;
}

body {padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box;}

.block__tabs {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--tabs-border-weight) * -1);
}

.block__tabs-item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
  border-left: var(--tabs-border-weight) solid var(--tabs-border-color);
  border-top: var(--tabs-border-weight) solid var(--tabs-border-color);
  background: var(--tabs-background);
  padding: .5em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.block__tabs-item::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, 
    transparent calc(50% - (var(--tabs-border-weight) / 2 + .25px)),
    var(--tabs-border-color),
    var(--tabs-background) calc(50% + (var(--tabs-border-weight) / 2 + .25px)));
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
}

.block__message {
  display: block;
  border: var(--tabs-border-weight) solid var(--tabs-border-color);
  background: var(--tabs-background);
  min-height: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__tabs">
    <div class="block__tabs-item">Заголовок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__message"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__tabs">
    <div class="block__tabs-item">Заголовок<br>Новая строка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__message"></div>
</div>
```